# Find $\lim_{x \to -8} \frac{\sqrt{1 - x} - 3 }{ 2 + \sqrt[3] {x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

How to find this limit?
$$\lim_{x \to -8} \frac{\sqrt{1 - x} - 3 }{ 2 + \sqrt[3] {x}}$$

#### Progress

I don't know Taylor series yet.  I tried to change variable $x$ to $t^3$ but I couldn't remove $(x + 8)$ factor, which creates $0$ in the denominator.

Comment: PLease exhibit your work on the problem and we will be glad to give some hints. How about expanding the root in the numerator into Taylor series around $x=1$?

Comment: @gt6989b I dont't know taylor series, I tried to change variable $x$ to $t^3$ but I couldn't remove $(x + 8)$ factor

Comment: Do you know derivatives? can you use L'Hospital's rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Why don't you multiply the top and bottom of the fraction by $\left(\sqrt{1-x}+3\right)$ and see what happens...

**Hint 2**

After you do simplify with hint 1, think of factoring $a^3 + b^3$...

**Update**

You get 
$$
\frac{\sqrt{1-x}-3}{2+\sqrt[3]{x}} \times \frac{\sqrt{1-x}+3}{\sqrt{1-x}+3}
= \frac{1-x - 3^2}{\left(2+\sqrt[3]{x}\right) \left(\sqrt{1-x}+3\right)}
= \frac{-(x+8)}{\left(2+\sqrt[3]{x}\right) \left(\sqrt{1-x}+3\right)}
$$
and the top factors as the sum of two cubes:
$$
8+x = 2^3+\left(\sqrt[3]{x}\right)^3 = \left(2+\sqrt[3]{x}\right)(\ldots)
$$
which should cancel nicely with the denominator. Can you finish it?

Comment: Ah, I tried hint 1 but I forgot to square the number $3$ in my last attempt. this is my biggest problem I always use the right way to solve but I make mistake in simple computing...

Comment: @omidh Please see the update, can you finish it now? Feel free to accept the solution when you understand it to the end...

Comment: sorry I forgot to tell you, yes I did. Thanks